# How do I get strings of assigned objects?

Tags: r

I want to be able to get the string of the assigned values

```
x <- 5
y <- 'something'
models  <- c(x, y)

for (model in models){
print(model)
}
```

The expected results should print `'x'` and `'y'`, while this way I am getting obviously `5` and `'something'`

How should I modify my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the vector `models`, R has no way to tell it was created from `x` and `y`, so you cannot recover these variable names from `models` unless you create `models` with this intention in mind. For example:

```r
x <- 5
y <- 'something'
models  <- c(quote(x), quote(y))

for(model in models){
  print(model)
}
#> x
#> y
```

Or even better:

```r
for (model in models){
  cat(model, ":", eval(model), "\n")
#> x : 5
#> y : something
```

An alternative might be to create a function which generates a list where both the variable name and its value are preserved:

```r
named_list <- function(...) setNames(list(...), 
                                     sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], deparse))

named_list(x, y)
#> $x
#> [1] 5
#>
#> $y
#> [1] "something"
```

Comment: Ideally, don't want the quote thing in the list of models because I use this list in a different task in my code. if this helps the x, and y are names of models got from OLS regressions, so is a `lm` object.

Comment: @msh855 do you mean x is an lm object and y is an lm object? Is there a problem using the second solution here?

Comment: yes, sorry for not being clear. The problem is that I want the list of x,y as in my post for later use.

Comment: @msh855 so why not use the function in the second part of my answer? That way you can do `mylist <- named_list(x, y)`, and you have the models in a list where you can retrieve either the models or the name of your models. Or is there something additional you need?

Comment: True, I second as second solution the second code

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use a list.

```
models <- list(x = 5,y = "something")

for (model in names(models)){
  print(model)
}
```